# Como mudar a visualização de botões alternados com base em um binding no DataGrid em WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Olá, sou novo com XAML/WPF e estou com o seguinte problema. Tenho um `DataGrid` que recebe como ItemsSource uma `ObservableCollection<DataEstoque>()` assim

```cs
public class DataEstoque
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Descricao { get; set; }
    public int WebCodigo { get; set; }
}
```

Na view, meu DataGrid fica declarado assim:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="DataGridProdutos" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ColumnWidth="Auto" 
          Margin="10" Background="White" IsReadOnly="True">
  <DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Id" Binding="{Binding Id}" Width="75" 
                        SortDirection="Ascending"/>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Descrição do produto" Width="*" 
                        Binding="{Binding Descricao}" />
    <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="auto">
      <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <DockPanel Margin="0, -3, 0, -3">
            <Button Click="VincularProduto" DockPanel.Dock="Left" Foreground="Green"
                    Style="{DynamicResource BtnLink}" Content="vincular"
                    Width="60" Height="24" Tag="{Binding Id}"
                    Visibility="{Binding WebCodigo, Source=WebCodigo,
                                 Converter={StaticResource VisibleConverter}, 
                                 ConverterParameter=WebCodigo, 
                                 FallbackValue=Visible}"/>
            <Button Click="AtualizarProduto" DockPanel.Dock="Left" Foreground="Blue"
                    Style="{DynamicResource BtnLink}" Content="atualizar" 
                    Width="60" Height="20"  Tag="{Binding Id}"
                    Visibility="{Binding WebCodigo, Source=WebCodigo,
                                 Converter={StaticResource VisibleConverter}, 
                                 ConverterParameter=WebCodigo,
                                 FallbackValue=Collapsed}"/>
                        </DockPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

A intenção é que, quando eu carregasse a `ObservableCollection<DataEstoque>` eu possa, baseado no converter que fiz mostrar ou não os botões mas não funciona. O converter foi feito assim:

```cs
public class VisibleConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
                          CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if ((value is string && string.IsNullOrEmpty((string)value)) ||
            (value is bool && !!(bool)value) ||
            (value is int && ((int)value) > 0) ||
            (value != null))
            return Visibility.Visible;

        return null;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, 
                              object parameter, CultureInfo culture) =>
        throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

O código do converter já foi testado, ele verifica o tipo do objeto enviado e, baseado nas referências ele retorna `Visible` ou null. Se retornado null, ele irá usar o `FallbackValue`. O problema é que, não consigo fazer o tratamento automático para cada linha no datagrid, e não é inteligente fazer um loop e forçar a visualização de um ou outro botão do datagrid.

Alguém sabe como resolver?

Answer (score 0):

Resolvi meu problema corrigindo meu converter... o problema era que na validação do tipo do objeto eu não comparava o mesmo corretamente. Também acrescentei um "inversor" ao resultado, caso eu queira negar o resultado da comparação. Assim:

```
public class VisibleConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        parameter.TryCast(out bool? invert);
        if (parameter is string && parameter.ToString().ToLower() == "false")
            invert = false;

        bool test = false;

        if (value.TryCast(out string stringValue))
            test = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(stringValue.Trim());
        else if (value.TryCast(out int intValue))
            test = intValue > 0;
        else if (value.TryCast(out bool boolValue))
            test = boolValue;
        else
            test = value != null;

        if (invert != null && !invert.toBool()) test = !test;

        if (test) return Visibility.Visible;

        return null;
    }
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, 
                              CultureInfo culture) =>
         throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

Sobre os métodos `object.TryCast<T>()` e o `bool?.toBool()`, tenho uma classe extensiva que contém os 2 métodos:

```cs
public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static bool toBool(this bool? value) => 
        value != null && value != false;
    public static bool TryCast<T>(this object obj, out T result)
    {
        if (obj is T)
        {
            result = (T)obj;
            return true;
        }

        result = default(T);
        return false;
    }
}
```